# Converting the sybase stuff function in to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Sybase query :

```
UPDATE #horizCallSign SET 
effDaysZ = STUFF( effDaysZ, csd.day+shift1, 1, '1')  
FROM #callSignTbl csd  
WHERE csd.legId1 = #horizCallSign.legId1  
AND   csd.legId2 = #horizCallSign.legId2  
AND   day = 28
```

Oracle Query :

```
UPDATE TEMP_HORIZ_CALL_SIGN  
SET  eff_Days_Z = REPLACE(  eff_days_Z,csd.day+shift1, '1')  
FROM temp_call_sign_table1 csd  
WHERE csd.leg_Id1 = temp_horiz_Call_Sign.leg_Id1  
AND   csd.leg_Id2 = horiz_Call_Sign.leg_Id2  
AND   day = 28
```

In Oracle, we have changed the column names with having "_" in them. 
temp_call_sign_table1 and TEMP_HORIZ_CALL_SIGN  are global temporary tables 
created for Oracle in place of sybase temp tables with on commit preserve 
rows.

We are converting sybase DB to Oracle DB. When I execute the above query in oracle it says  QL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with your table name on line 5, this is easily avoided by using aliases.

Also, you can't use FROM in Oracle without a SELECT. Thus a sub-query must be used in this instance. For example...

```
UPDATE TEMP_HORIZ_CALL_SIGN hcs 
SET eff_Days_Z =
(SELECT
    REPLACE(eff_days_Z,csd.day+shift1, '1')  
 FROM temp_call_sign_table1 csd  
 WHERE csd.leg_Id1 = hcs.leg_Id1  
 AND   csd.leg_Id2 = hcs.leg_Id2  
 AND   day = 28)
```

(Not tested)

Comment: HI Matt, The above query works in SQL developer but it fails when i run it through my program. Please find the below error. [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01407: cannot update ("PEGASUSDB_SCHEMA"."TEMP_HORIZ_CALL_SIGN"."EFF_DAYS_Z") to NULL

Comment: @sandeep Sorry, I don't know of any reason why a NULL would be present when running outside of the IDE

Answer (score 0):

Your are off on your aliasing. Also, consider using INNER JOINS instead.

```
UPDATE THCS
SET  eff_Days_Z = REPLACE(  eff_days_Z,csd.day+shift1, '1')  
FROM temp_call_sign_table1 csd  , TEMP_HORIZ_CALL_SIGN THCS,  horiz_Call_Sign HCS
WHERE csd.leg_Id1 = THCS.leg_Id1  
AND   csd.leg_Id2 = HCS.leg_Id2  
AND   day = 28
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, You can use `MERGE INTO`.

```
MERGE INTO temp_horiz_call_sign m
using (SELECT leg_id1,
              leg_id2,
              eff_days_z,
              day + shift1 plushift1
       FROM   temp_call_sign_table1
       WHERE  day = 28) r
ON ( r.leg_id1 = m.leg_id1
     AND r.leg_id2 = m.leg_id2 )
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET m.eff_days_z = Replace(m.eff_days_z, r.plushift1, '1');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Appreciate it